# Is there a way to comment on an Instagram post a user has been tagged using Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to be able to comment on Instagram posts where a user has been tagged using the Instagram Graph API.

Example:

- UserA posts PostX and tags UserB in the post.
- UserB is a business and connected to a Instagram App. UserB will receive a webhook they've been tagged in PostX
- What I'd like to achieve: UserB adds a comment on PostX through IG Graph API.

My research shows that the `comments` endpoint is only available for posts the user owns ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/comments)).

IG user mentions only allow commenting on posts where a user has either mentioned UserB in the caption or a comment ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/mentions)).

What I'm missing to find is the ability to comment on @tagged posts.